# How to Post Back from PopUp In jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I have following buttons in My **PopUp in jQueryMobile** i.e.

- HTML Submit Button,
- ASP Link Button
- Anchor and
- ASP Button

  ```
  <input type="submit"  value="click" onserverclick="input_Click"/><br>
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="input_Click" data-role="button">link< /asp:LinkButton><br>
  <a href="#"  data-role="button" onserverclick="input_Click" >anc< /a><br>
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" runat="server" Text="btn" OnClick="input_Click" data-role="button"/ >
  ```

Only `ASP Link Button` Is Capable of Posting Back to the Code Behind i.e. to `input_Click` handler in `aspx.cs` ,  When Clicked From POPUP,

PopUp is below:

```
 <div id="div123" data-role="popup"><br>
 <myControl:testcontrol ID="ctltest" runat="server"></bt:testcontrol><br>< /div><br>
 <a href="#div123" data-rel="popup" >open</a><br>
```

Why other buttons Cant do this ?
How Post Back takes place Inside POPUP in jQM ?

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed on the following page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> This means that any scripts and styles referenced in the head of a
>   page won't have any effect when a page is loaded via Ajax, but they
>   **will execute if the page is requested normally via HTTP**. When
>   scripting jQuery Mobile sites, both scenarios need to be considered.
>   The reason that the head of a page is ignored when requested via Ajax
>   is that the potential of re-executing the same JavaScript is very high
>   (it's common to reference the same scripts in every page of a site).
>   Due to the complexity of attempting to work around that issue, we
>   leave the task of executing page-specific scripts to the developer,
>   and assume head scripts are only expected to execute once per browsing
>   session.

So when you launch a dialog, it loads the `page` and has no access to the original JavaScript. I often embed `<script></script>` into the dialog someplace so that it loads when the dialog is opened.

Comment: thanx..this is true.. bt how to post back values from popup..???
i have a textbox and on Button click I am unable to catch its Values on CodeBehind..i get " " value :(

Comment: Bind a function to the closing of the dialog box or the submitting of the form. Can post the data via `$.post()` or assign it globally.